# Appending text to field name while using replicate() method in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

I can replicate a table row using the code below, but what I need is to be able to append the word "COPY" to the new rows name field so its easy to distinguish from the original row and I am not sure where to start.

**index.blade.php**

```
...
<div class="py-1">
   <a wire:click="replicate({{$generator->id}})"
      ...
      Clone
   </a>
</div>
...
```

**index.php**

```
...
public function replicate($id)
{
    $record = Generator::find($id);
    $newRecord = $record->replicate()->save();
}
...
```

**annotated screenshot**
[image]

Comment: set that attribute how you want before you call `save` on the model, `replicate` returns a model instance, just set the attribute to what you want

Comment: @lagbox Is the attribute set by stringing it after replicate()?  The name field is 'generator_name' -- would you mind providing me with an example--I am still feeling around in the dark.  Thank you.

Comment: good luck with the rest of your project :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set the attribute as you want it like any other model instance as `replicate` returns a new model instance:

```
public function replicate($id)
{
    $newRecord = Generator::findOrFail($id)->replicate();

    $newRecord->generator_name .= ' COPY';

    $newRecord->save();
    ...
}
```